# Java RethinkDB Expected type DATUM but found SELECTION

Tags: java, types, rethinkdb, nosql

I'm using RethinkDB driver for Java. I want to filter the rows without field `endedAt` in table `jam` like this:

```
public List<Jam> getCurrent(){
        Cursor cursor = r.table("jam")
                .filter(row -> row.hasFields("endedAt")).not()
                .run(conn);
        List<Map<String,Object>> list=cursor.toList();
        return list.stream().map(item->JamRepository.toJam(item)).collect(Collectors.toList());
    }
```

And I've got this error `Expected type DATUM but found SELECTION Java`

I have another filter function in another class:

```
public List<Speedlog> getByTime(long time){
        Cursor cursor = r.table("speedlog")
                .filter(row -> row.g("createdAt").eq(time))
                .run(conn);
        List<Map<String,Object>> list=cursor.toList();
        return list.stream().map(item->SpeedlogRepository.toSpeedlog(item)).collect(Collectors.toList());
    }
```

This function works properly

Could anyone please explain what makes the difference between these two? Why does `getCurrent` function get that error? What is its meaning and how to fix? Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`not()` should be right after `row.hasFields("endedAt")`. For now you are trying to call `not()` on the result of `filter` function. So, correct code:

```
public List<Jam> getCurrent(){
        Cursor cursor = r.table("jam")
                .filter(row -> row.hasFields("endedAt").not())
                .run(conn);
        List<Map<String,Object>> list=cursor.toList();
        return list.stream().map(item->JamRepository.toJam(item)).collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```