# A Java filtered cursor that fails

Tags: java, filter, cursor, rethinkdb

Very similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40206697/java-rethinkdb-expected-type-datum-but-found-selection) cursor question except that my code does not work. The cursor is empty. The filter snippet is this:

```
Cursor cursor = r.table(tableName)
                .filter(row -> row.g(filterKey).eq(filterValue))
                .run(conn);
```

where `filterKey = "type"` and `filterValue = "AffiliationGraphType"`

Below an example row to find is this:

```
{
    "inE": {},
    "inEID": ["57d93bfd-fd70-44d4-9749-9a651987e60d", "c1a3b465-0ee5-4280-ab07-99782037b9aa"],
    "outE": {},
    "id": "16321._Bernau_bei_Berlin._Allemagne.",
    "label": "16321, Bernau bei Berlin, Allemagne.",
    "type": "AffiliationGraphType"
}
```

My code looks just like the linked code, but it is not landing any hits. How can I improve on this code?

Answer (score 0):

I realized (!) that the JSON data is, itself, in the internal map under the key "cargo", so the fix is:

```
 .filter(row -> row.g("cargo").g(filterKey).eq(filterValue))
```